# Bash file Output not omitting Query

Tags: bash, sh

The issue is, The first line inside a file has **{**some test here**}**

The curly Brackets wont allow my output to display,

I have put text without the {} inside the file and it outputs okay.

I would like to output all text including curly brackets

```
rm -rf /var/www/html/data/php/data.txt
echo -e "${info}Waiting to read from file. ${cyan}Press ${red}Ctrl + C ${cyan}to exit...\n"
while true; do

    if [[ -e "/var/www/html/data/php/data.txt" ]]; then
        echo -e "\007${success}New data detected!\n"
        while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo -e  "$line"
         echo -e "${green}[${blue}*${green}]${yellow} $line"
        done < /var/www/html/data/php/data.txt
        cat /var/www/html/data/php/data >> "$cwd/data.txt"
        rm -rf data.txt
    fi
    sleep 0.5
    
done
```

Comment: In which line are you trying to print the file data? I don't see it here.

Comment: Supposedly this is a missing line right after `while IFS= ...`?

Comment: Yes I have and its not outputting anything still but when I remove the {} it works all okay.  I need the {} too.

Comment: Instead of using `echo -e`, can you try `printf "%s" "${line}"`? Unrelated, but I think the `cat` line is missing the file extension (`.txt`). Are the newlines Windows style? What do you get by running `head data.txt | xxd` after the first `7d`? `0a` or `0d0a`?

Comment: printf "%s" "${line}"  Thank you . This is the answer. It works.

Comment: That's good the problem though it that we don't know exactly why it's not working with `echo` LOL